# ElasticSearch result sorting (relevant score) based on certain field (boosting)

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ElasticSearch 6.6. My application builds ES index by pulling data from different data sources. The search does not specify the data source. It just builds a query something like:

```
GET employerdata/_search
{ 
  "query": 
  { 
    "bool": {
      "must": [
          {  "match" : {"name" : {
        "query": "WALMART",
        "fuzziness": "3"
      }}},
          {  "match" : {"state" : "TX"}}
        ]
    } 
  }

}
```

There is a field called "dataSource". However, it is not used to build a query. However, it is a part of the result. Basically, I want to make use of this field implicitly while building a query. for example If the document has "dataSource" equals "A" then the document should be at the top of the result set. In other words, I want to boost the score based on the field "dataSource". However, I still want to get the result even if the document was index from other "dataSource" such as "B".

Comment: It would be nice to respond to our answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on top of @apt-get_install_skill answer. If boosting is needed at query time instead of indexing. You can use [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

```
GET employer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "dataSource": "B"
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you jaspreet chahal for the tip. I was able to accomplish it by building a query which looked like:

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the boost-parameter you can add to your **queries** (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/mapping-boost.html). You set this boost to certain values of your fields (e.g. dataSource = A). This is not a filter (dataSource = B will still get returned) but it increases the relevance of the particular documents that match the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
GET employerdata/_search
{ 
 "query": 
 { 
"function_score": {
  "query": {"bool": {
  "must": [
      {  "match" : {"beName" : {
    "query": "KROGER",
    "fuzziness": "3"
  }}},
      {  "match" : {"beZip" : "47119"}}
    ]
} },
  "functions": [
    { "filter": {"match": {"dataSource" : "eeo1"}},
      "random_score": { },
      "weight": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

}

}